# Laravel and shared hosting security concern

Tags: laravel-4

I have finished my website with laravel. It's cool, and everything works fine but. Now it's th hardest moment. I need to deploy it. I ask my web provider to upgrade my provider for dynamic website. They answer me they cannot host laravel because security concern.

1)What kind of security concern could be in installing laravel?

2) I have to ask for a VPS or it's just my provider who has this policy? IF for example i go for this http://www.ovh.co.uk/web-hosting/web-hosting-pro.xml I can host laravel?

3) I just need to copy everything from my localhost to them?

SOrry for the noobies question but I never deploy a website until now and I am a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

It is just that your web host does not support it.

I can host laravel project on this web host: https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/ You just need to copy your project folder into somewhere in your public directory. Then make sure storage folder in your root laravel project folder has 777 permission. Otherwise you got a blank page.

Go to the url corresponding to the public folder in your project.